# About the usage of been been in the passive sentence

Tags: grammar

Respected sir,
     I want to know that if i can use "been" instead of "being" in the passive form of perfect continuous tense. Ex - I have been beating you. You have been been beaten by me. Is it a correct sentence. Guide me

Comment: *You have been **being** beaten* -- the perfect construction requires *HAVE* + a following past participle, the progressive construction requires *BE* + a following present participle, the passive construction requires *BE* + a following past participle.

Comment: @StoneyB That reminds me of a sentence from a course book:  _By September, that bridge will have been being built for three years_.

Comment: is my answer wrong then............